# Angular2 passing value from template to function on buttonclick

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 form template of component like this:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group">
    <label> Masukkan nik </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" #name>
  </div>
     <button (click)="verifyNik(name.value)">Verify</button>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

What I want to do if I click the `Verify` button is to get the value of name input and pass it to my function in my component, which is like this below:

```
verifyNik(nik){
    if(this.idparam==nik.substring(1,4)){
      console.log("true");
    }
  }
```

So, if the value of input name in template (and substring it) is equal to my `id.param` (which I get from subscribe id in Angular route), then the console log will be true; but the problem is that nothing comes out. How can I fix this?

My code to get my `id.param` is this:

```
private idchild:any;
  f: FormGroup;
  private idparam:any;


  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private servicedev:DevService,
    private complaintservice:ComplaintService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

     ngOnInit() {
        this.idchild = this.router.params.subscribe(params => {

           let id = params['id'];
           this.idparam=id;

          // Retrieve Pet with Id route param

       });
```

Comment: You should add an ngModel to the input and then grab it's value

Comment: Are you using `FormControl` in HTML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <label> Masukkan nik </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" 
   aria-describedby="basic-addon1" #name>
</div>
<button (click)="verifyNik(name)">Verify</button>
```

then in your .ts

```
verifyNik(nik) {
  if(this.idparam == nik.value.substring(1, 4)) {
    console.log("true");
  }
}
```

Comment: @dedypuji happy to help

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected even inside ngFor.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `FormControl` of the `FormBuilder` your using. Check below code snippet

**HTML Code Snippet**

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(testForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Masukkan nik </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [formControl]="testForm.controls['name']" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
    <div *ngIf="testForm.controls['name'].hasError('required') && testForm.controls['name'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">Name field cannot be empty.</div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" [disabled]="!testForm.valid">Verify</button>
</form>
```

Above you could see that I have `form` tag with the `formGroup` name defined as `testForm` and `ngSubmit` calling `submitForm` method with `testForm` instance values

Apart from that I have defining an `ngModel` and `FormControl` for the input tag. Additionally I have added Required constraint message. A button type `submit`since i am using ngSubmit to submit the whole form. and a disable feature to disable button if the form is not valid.

Lets check the component in the below code snippet

**Component Code Snippet**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = new User('');
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.testForm = fb.group({
      'name': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  submitForm(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

You have to create a `User` Model with desired attributes. Use it to create `user` instance which will be used in the `ngModel` in html to bind data (two binding) Create `testForm` instance of `FormBuilder` in the constructor and with the `required` constraint. Check the `submitForm` method, `console.log` will trigger once u click `Verify` button with the value

Answer (score 2):

Give a try Like this

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group">
    <label> Masukkan nik </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name"placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" #name>
  </div>
     <button (click)="verifyNik(name)">Verify</button>

</div>

verifyNik(nik){
    if(this.idparam==nik.substring(1,4)){
      console.log("true");
    }
  }
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QSnTt7AeOg7d1bw1duB3?p=preview)

Comment: it return error like this sir Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label> Masukkan nik </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" #name="ngModel">
            </div>
            <button (click)="verifyNik(name)">Verify</button>
        </div>
```

your TS

```
    model = {
        name : null
    };
    private idparam = "FooBar";

    verifyNik(obj) {
        if (this.idparam === obj.viewModel.substring(1, 4)) {
            console.info("true");
        }
    }
```

or

```
    <div class="input-group">
                <label> Masukkan nik </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" #name="ngModel">
            </div>
            <button (click)="verifyNik(model.name)">Verify</button>

    verifyNik(obj) {
        if (this.idparam === obj.substring(1, 4)) {
            console.info("true");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button #ee value="sravan" name="b1"(click)="fun(ee.value)">button 1</button>
<button #ff name="b2" value="buttontwo"(click)="fun(ff.value)">button 2</button>
<button #hh name="b3"value="buttonthree"(click)="fun(hh.value)">button3</button>
<button #kk name="b4" value="buttonfour"(click)="fun(kk.value)">button4</button>
<button  #ll name="b5"value="buttonfive"(click)="fun(ll.value)">button5</button>

value = {{selecte}}



    <input type="text"  #name>

  <button (click)="ver(name.value)">Verify</button>



ts:

selecte:any;
fun(data:string){
  this.selecte=data;
}

ver(sara:string) {

  console.log(sara);
}
```

Comment: What is the question you need help with?